# How to populate an Android Spinner from ArrayMap

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

How should I use an ArrayMap<String, CustomClass> to be the data source for a Spinner in Android? I would like it to use the .name field of the CustomClass as label in the Spinner. The map is dynamic as it contains devices that are detected.

Answer (score 0):

Usually for Spinners, Map types are not recommended for creating array adapter. Because maps does not maintain order. So for example if you need do something based on position , it might not work as intended.

If you definitely need to use `ArrayMap` , here is the code to do that. You need to convert values of map values `toList` and pass it to adapter. And to control the text, you need to override `toString` method for custom class, which will be the data shown in spinner.

```
class Foo constructor(var foo: String,var bar:String){
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "$foo:$bar"
    }
}

    val arrayMap = ArrayMap<String,Foo>()
    arrayMap["cde"] = Foo("Some","Content")
    arrayMap["abc"] = Foo("Hello","World")
    val dataAdapter2 = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayMap.values.toList())
```

In spinner it will show like below,
`Hello:World`
`Some:Content`